# miner_proxy and minerd Settings

Tags: litecoin, nodes, connection

I've started a mining account of Wemineltc.com, and have decided to go down the track of CPU mining.  I looked up the relative tutorials on how to do so, and I got some different results.  I set the proxy batch file to

```
mining_proxy.exe -o freedom.wemineltc.com -p3339
```

and the minerd batch file to

```
minerd -a scrypt -o stratum+tcp://freedom.wemineltc.com:3339 -O USER.1:12345
```

One of the tutorials says instead to use the minerd command line of

```
minderd -a scrypt http://127.0.0.1:8332 -O USER.1:12345
```

I tried the latter minerd command line and it didn't mine, so I tried my own version.  Is there any explanation to this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes. [mining_proxy](https://github.com/slush0/stratum-mining-proxy) is used to translate from stratum to the old getwork protocol. This is useful if you want to use a mining program that does not support stratum, but you still want to get the benefits of stratum.

However, minerd supports stratum out of the box. You don't need mining_proxy.

You should remove the first and third commands.